# How to render another child component in react due to another child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

A component has 2 child components, on changing the switch value in one of the child component, it should re-render the other child component. How to achieve this? Please explain with a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components render/rerender for one of a couple reasons:

1. The component enqueues a state update.
2. The parent component rerenders.

Causing case 2 is the simplest way to achieve what you ask. The parent component of both children just needs some declared state that child 1 can call a callback prop when it updates its local state to trigger the parent component to rerender itself and its sub-ReactTree.

Example:

```js
const Child1 = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    onChange(value);
  }, [onChange, value]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Child 1</h1>
      <label>
        Value
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.checked)}
        />
      </label>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const Child2 = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Child 2 render " + new Date());
  });

  return <h1>Child 2</h1>;
};

function App() {
  const [, rerender] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child1 onChange={rerender} />
      <Child2 />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

There are other ways to trigger sibling components to rerender via a common ancestor component, like a React Context provider.

Comment: Components doesn't re-render because of "props change"

Comment: @NickOlay You might be right. I guess a prop value changing is masked, or subsumed, by the fact the parent component rerendered in order to provide any updated prop values. I thought I could recall some specific React documentation covering this topic but it eludes me at the moment.